# What is a stateful firewall and how does it work?

Tags: firewall

Could someone, please, explain what a statefull firewall is and how it works? Also, it would be helpful if you can compare it to a stateless firewall.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall

Answer (score 2):

Stateful means it tracks connections, looks at the 3 way handshake, the SYN, the ACK e.t.c. It knows if a packet is going out to make a new connection. It knows if a packet is part of an existing connection.

Stateless means it doesn't. It just looks at IP,PORT, whether the packet is going in or out (direction of the packet).  Stateful can do that and more

If it's stateless, it means you can't specify to allow in established connections, or to allow in/out new connections..  You can just specify e.g. allow all packets in on this port from this/these IPs.

If you run a server and want the firewall to let packets through for that server, then it's fine for allowing packets to the server. You allow in all packets, and allow out all packets, and you might restrict some IPs.   So no difference there whether stateful or stateless.

But if you want to browse the web, then if it was a stateful firewall, you can say Allow all packets out on port 80, and allow ESTABLISHED ones in or out.  (this is common with iptables) So the only packets that come in, are ones that are part of an already established connection. The packets going out are to make a new connection or are part of an existing connection, or rather, everything can go out, not deny rule. that's a common configuration. A rule in iptables to allow in packets from established connections `-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` from the iptables article "Towards a perfect ruleset"  http://inai.de/documents/Perfect_Ruleset.pdf

Or, what is done with ipfw, allow an outgoing connection on port 80, and any packets associated with that connection can go in or out. That's stateful.  `allow tcp from any to any 80 out setup keep-state`

A stateless firewall doesn't track connections.. I haven't used one so while I know its limitations, off hand i'm not sure the best ways to configure web browsing with it, but I suppose you'd have to allow in packets from port 80 to any port>1023. And allow out all packets to port 80. If you were running a server on a high port (some do for security), then it'd be quite insecure because anybody could connect to it because of such a relaxed rule for browsing the web, so I suppose you'd put any server on a low port. That said, I haven't used a stateless rule to allow web browsing. I'm not sure of the most secure ways to do it. Though I don't think anybody would use a stateless firewall, especially not for that.